# Export not working for connected component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
class Test extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {};
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Test);
```

I got a component like this above. I am trying to export it from another file say (index.js) in the below fashion.The path is correct i have checked that.

```
export  Test  from "./test.jsx";
```

But connected component is not getting exported from this file. Am I doing something wrong ? If i am exporting the class and importing it like the following its working

```
 export  {Test}  from "./test.jsx";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code line below

```
export  Test  from "./test.jsx";
```

Into

```
export { default }  from "./test.jsx";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Nope it still can't resolve it back to the connected export, it throws error `from "./test.jsx"`

Comment: I found the solution from Mozilla documentation page, can you try that one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
import Test  from "./test.jsx";
export Test;
```